# Mandelbrot optimization in openmp

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp, mandelbrot

Well i have to paralellisize the mandelbrot program in C. I think i have done it well and i cant get better times. My question if someone has an idea to improve the code, ive been thinking perhaps in nested parallel regions between the outer and insider for...

Also i have doubts if its more elegant or recommended to put all the pragmas in a single line or to write separate pragmas ( one for omp parallel and shared and private variables and a conditional, and another pragma with omp for and schedule dynamic).

Ive the doubt if constants can be used as private variables because i think is cleaner to have constants instead of defined variables.

Also i have written a conditional ( if numcpu >1) it has no sense to use parallel region and make a normal sequential execution.

Finally as i have read the dynamic chunk it depends on hardware and your system configuration... so i have left it as a constant, so it can be easily changed.

Also i adapt the number of threads to the number of processors available..

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    omp_set_dynamic(1);

    int xactual, yactual;

    //each iteration, it calculates: newz = oldz*oldz + p, where p is the current pixel, and oldz stars at the origin
    double pr, pi;                   //real and imaginary part of the pixel p
    double newRe, newIm, oldRe, oldIm;   //real and imaginary parts of new and old z
    double zoom = 1, moveX = -0.5, moveY = 0; //you can change these to zoom and change position

    pixel_t *pixels = malloc(sizeof(pixel_t)*IMAGEHEIGHT*IMAGEWIDTH);
    clock_t begin, end;
    double time_spent;    

    begin=clock();

    int numcpu;
    numcpu = omp_get_num_procs();

    //FILE * fp;
    printf("El número de procesadores que utilizaremos es: %d", numcpu);

    omp_set_num_threads(numcpu);

    #pragma omp parallel shared(pixels, moveX, moveY, zoom) private(xactual, yactual, pr, pi, newRe, newIm) (if numcpu>1)
    {
        //int xactual=0;
    //  int yactual=0;
        #pragma omp for  schedule(dynamic, CHUNK)       

    //loop through every pixel
        for(yactual = 0; yactual < IMAGEHEIGHT; yactual++)
            for(xactual = 0; xactual < IMAGEWIDTH; xactual++)
            {
                //calculate the initial real and imaginary part of z, based on the pixel location and zoom and position values
            pr = 1.5 * (xactual - IMAGEWIDTH / 2) / (0.5 * zoom * IMAGEWIDTH) + moveX;
            pi = (yactual - IMAGEHEIGHT / 2) / (0.5 * zoom * IMAGEHEIGHT) + moveY;
            newRe = newIm = oldRe = oldIm = 0; //these should start at 0,0
            //"i" will represent the number of iterations
            int i;
            //start the iteration process
            for(i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++)
            {
                //remember value of previous iteration
                oldRe = newRe;
                oldIm = newIm;
                //the actual iteration, the real and imaginary part are calculated
                newRe = oldRe * oldRe - oldIm * oldIm + pr;
                newIm = 2 * oldRe * oldIm + pi;
                //if the point is outside the circle with radius 2: stop
                if((newRe * newRe + newIm * newIm) > 4) break;
            }

            //            color(i % 256, 255, 255 * (i < maxIterations));
            if(i == ITERATIONS)
            {
                //color(0, 0, 0); // black
                pixels[yactual*IMAGEWIDTH+xactual][0] = 0;
                pixels[yactual*IMAGEWIDTH+xactual][1] = 0;
                pixels[yactual*IMAGEWIDTH+xactual][2] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                double z = sqrt(newRe * newRe + newIm * newIm);
                int brightness = 256 * log2(1.75 + i - log2(log2(z))) / log2((double)ITERATIONS);

                //color(brightness, brightness, 255)
                pixels[yactual*IMAGEWIDTH+xactual][0] = brightness;
                pixels[yactual*IMAGEWIDTH+xactual][1] = brightness;
                pixels[yactual*IMAGEWIDTH+xactual][2] = 255;
            }      

      }

    }   //end of parallel region

    end= clock();

    time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    fprintf(stderr, "Elapsed time: %.2lf seconds.\n", time_spent);
```

Comment: Yes, the way to improve the speed of your code is to use SIMD. I do this with SSE and AVX. Is this for a x86 processor? If you add the SIMD and or SSE or AVX tag you will probably get a better answer.

Comment: You may also be interested in the code here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48069990/multithreaded-simd-vectorized-mandelbrot-in-r-using-rcpp-openmp

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the implementation to leverage SIMD extensions. As far as I know the latest OpenMP standard includes vector constructs. Check out [this article](http://www.hpctoday.com/hpc-labs/explicit-vector-programming-with-openmp-4-0-simd-extensions/) that describes the new capabilities.

This [whitepaper](http://saluc.engr.uconn.edu/refs/processors/intel/sse3.pdf) explains how SSE3 can be used when calculating the Mandelbrot set.

Comment: SIMD is a good suggestion. That's one of the tools I employ to speed up the Mandelbrot calculation.